# If $\tau$ is a stopping time with $\text P[\tau>s+t]=\text P[\tau>s]\text P[\tau>t]$, how do we determine the rate of the exponential distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution, levy-processes

Let $X$ be a càdlàg Lévy process, $\pi$ denote the unique random measure with $$\pi_\omega([0,t]\times B)=\sum_{s\in[0,\:t]}1_B\left({\Delta X_s(\omega)}\right),$$ where $\Delta x(t):=x(t)-\lim_{s\to t-}x(s)$, $$\zeta_t(\omega,B):=\pi_\omega([0,t]\times B)$$ and $$\tau:=\inf\{t>0:\Delta X_t\in B\}$$ for some Borel measurable $B$ with $0\not\in\overline B$.

> We can show that $$\operatorname P[\tau>s+t]=\operatorname P[\tau>s]\operatorname P[\tau>t]\tag1.$$ Since $$\phi(t):=\operatorname P[\tau>t]$$ is right-continuous, this implies that $$\phi(t)=e^{t\ln\phi(1)}\tag2.$$
>
> **Question**: By the result above, $\tau$ is exponentially distributed, but how do we see that $\tau\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$, where $\lambda:=\operatorname E\left[\zeta_1(\;\cdot\;,B)\right]$?

Clearly, $$\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)((t,\infty))=e^{-\lambda t}\tag3.$$ So, it seems like we need to show $$\ln\phi(1)=-\lambda(B).\tag4$$ But how do we do this?

### **BOUNTY EDIT**

I still don't understand how we obtain $(4)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A \to \pi_{\omega}(A \times B)$ is the random measure corresponding to a Poisson process on $[0,\infty)$. The rate of this Poisson process, is also the rate of the exponential waiting time for the first point of the process. See [Jumps of Lévy process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018248/jumps-of-l%C3%A9vy-process). So what is being used here is a simple but powerful property of the Poisson process on a halfline: The rate $\lambda$ of the exponential waiting time for the first point of the process, equals the expected number of points of the process that land in the unit interval.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_point_process_on_the_real_line

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not that I don't understand that $\tau$ has an exponential distribution. But I don't understand how we obtain $(4)$. Could you show this?

Comment: @0xbadf00d  i edited my answer to emphasize that what is used here is a general property of the Poisson point process on the line.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How do we see that this process is actually measurable? I've asked a separate question for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4407224/show-that-sum-substacks-ge0-delta-x-s-ne01-bs-delta-x-s-is-measurab. Would be great if you could take a look.